# How to create responsive List form with PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, modern-team-site, responsive, powerapps-forms

I customize the list form with PowerApps.
Since this site is also used from mobile, so I want to make the items in this customized form change according to the screen size.
But PowerApps via SPO seems out of the ordinary and has no settings to make it responsive.
Is it possible to make responsive customize form?
How did you solve this problem?
It would be very helpful if you could tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: please give me infomation about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid not.

We will need to build a custom **app** for an existing SharePoint list using Power Apps, in order to use responsive design in browser or on mobile devices.

Reference:
[Create a Power App for a list in SharePoint Online.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-power-app-for-a-list-in-sharepoint-online-9338b2d2-67ac-4b81-8e67-97da27e5e9ab)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it possible to use SPFx parts from Power Apps's canvas app?

Comment: @user91060 Sure we can integrate PowerApps with SPFx web parts, SPFx solution calls the PowerApps form using Modal Dialog with iFrame. Please see the references: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/integrate-powerapps-with-spfx-web-part/ ; https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52935.sharepoint-online-integrate-power-apps-canvas-form-with-spfx.aspx

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. Does that link mean to create a custom button in SharePoint Online with SPFx and call PowerApps from that button? My understanding is right?

Comment: @user91060 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, creating a responsive PowerApps canvas app called from that custom button would meet my initial needs, right?